# How to catch error or warning while getting data from database

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a problem. I am trying, but I am not getting the exact solution.

I have code to take something from database.

```
try {
    require_once('blogic.php');
    $obj  = new blogic();
    $re   = $obj->select("SELECT link FROM eff ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
    $l    = mysql_fetch_row($re);
    $link = $l[0];
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $link = "http://www.xyz.com/friendsin2013/";
}
```

The above code is working properly, but if (for whatever reason) any problem comes while getting data from the database, I want the link to be defaulted as given in the `catch` block.

However it is not working the way I want it to. It works when there is no error, however, when I experience an errorr, `$link` does not get passed from the `catch`.  I just get the error message instead.

Blogic.php life is like --->> This is a file to get database entry.

```
<?php

include('s.php');

class blogic {

    function connect() {
        $link = mysql_connect(SERVER, USER, PASSWORD);
        if (!$link) {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    function select_database() {
        $db = mysql_select_db(DATABASE);
        if (!$db) {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    function select($str) {
        self::connect();
        self::select_database();

        $res = mysql_query($str);
        return $res;
    }
}
?>
```

s.php ->>

Comment: It may not help answer your question, but you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://www.deprecatedphp.com/mysql_/).

Comment: I'm not sure that's how `try-catch` statements work. `$link` may be out of scope at this point, so you should try to `return` it in the `catch` block.

Comment: @Matt link to your own website? Em..

Comment: @riwette it doesn't generate revenue; it's just there for informational purposes, and the bulk of the information is on other sites, which I link to.

Answer (score 0):

Write this as a function, then call it; return `$link` in both the `try` and `catch` blocks:

```
require_once('blogic.php');

function getLink() {
     try {
        $obj = new blogic();
        $re=$obj->select("SELECT link FROM eff ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
        $l=mysql_fetch_row($re);
        return $l[0];
    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
        return "http://www.xyz.com/friendsin2013/";
    }
}

$link = getLink();
```

Comment: Thanks, will it also catch PHP warnings? I know this will catch any error took place, but if any warning came then will it also go into catch block ?

Comment: This will not catch warnings; just `Exception`s. If you want a custom error handler for warnings, check out [`set_error_handler()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php).

Answer (score 0):

Is `$link` defined before the `try`/`catch` logic? If not try that first.

`$link` looks to not be accessible outside the `try`/`catch` with the code provided.

Though Matt beat me to the best answer; go with his is at all possible.